# How to set exchanges in AMQP with cloudevents sdk-go

Tags: go, cloudevents

I need to send messages in rabbitMQ broker, but with use cloudevents sdk-go library based on azure-amqp protocol.
I know how to set exchanges with streadway-amqp but I need to use a new version of amqp (1+). And for this case, I need to use cloudevents sdk-go library.
I found, that when we create a new protocol, we set address and node. Node - is a message queue in broker.
But I want that new protocol to create an exchange, not a queue. How I can do that? Can I do that?)